# Are Google App Engine deployed files private by default?

Tags: google-app-engine

Excuse the naivety here, I'm new to GAE, and haven't been able to find much in the available literature / answers about the deployed filesystem's public status...

My question is quite simple:

Assuming a standard `app.yaml` config, are the files that get pushed to GAE with `gcloud app deploy` publicly inaccessible, unless exposed by (in the example of Node.js) an express endpoint?

I want to make sure sensitive data like key files (for reference in code) in our deployed bundle are not exposed, and that the local filesystem of a deployment is only accessible privately by the code itself.

Comment: Yes, they are..

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you work with the “static” files & dir directives no data should be made visible to outside users by Google.

Authenticated Admin users (youself) can see all files deployed to the server in the admin console unless you disable “code downloads” (which was available on legacy App Engine but seems to be removed now).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @max — accepting as it answers my question about public access! Although I was unable to find anything but deprecated docs about disabling code downloads, e.g. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/downloading-source-code -- not immediately relevant to the question but might be worth revising?